# How can I see source of broken hyperlinks on PDF document?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

I have a PDF document with a number hyperlinks inside which (I believe) are URL links.

However, when I click these hyperlinks, nothing happens. They are broken.

Is it possible for me to see where these hyperlinks were *intended* to go? I may need to somehow break down the PDF file or use special software.

I am on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: `pdf-link-checker` fails to install on `Python 2.7.13`, it looks like a missing dependency called `pdfminer`